# Windows 10 File Sharing fails, but can access shared folder using RUN -> \\OTHER_PC\Shared_Folder succeeds

Tags: windows, networking, network-shares

I have two Windows 10 PCs on our home private LAN - one an XPS13, the other an XPS15.  I have C:\Users\Public shared on the XPS13. I have file sharing turned ON under 'Private Networks', and password protections turned OFF under 'All Networks'. Both PC's are hard-wired into the LAN.

I can 'see' the XPS13 from the XPS15 in file explorer, but if I click to expand it, I get "JOXPS13 is not accessible.  You might not have permissions to use this network resource..."

However, if I bring up the RUN window on my XPS15 and type in "\JOXPS13\PUBLIC", I get a file explorer window with 'Network > JOXPS13 > public' (\Joxps13\public) shown in the top, and I can access anything within this directory. I verified this is a 'live' link by moving a file into that directory on JOXPS13 and verified that it immediately becomes visible on my XPS15.

When I started this troubleshooting effort, I noticed I couldn't ping from XPS15 to XPS13, and I traced this back to the McAfee firewall on both systems.  Reverting both firewalls to "Default Settings" fixed this problem, but the above file sharing issue remains.

The only odd thing I can see in the setup is that my XPS15 shows it is connected to 'ARRIS-53BF' (our cable router) and 'internet access', but the XPS13 shows 'HOME-5GHZ' (one of our 2 wireless access points) and 'connected', even though the network symbol is the one for a wired connection - not wireless, and it is physically connected via a cat-5 ethernet cable.

Thoughts?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

This is working as expected, and as designed.

If you could view JOXPS13 directly, that would give access to the entire HDD, a security no-no. You've shared \Public, and have remote access to that directory.

In addition, Windows does not always show other PC's on the network. [Network Discovery](https://www.dummies.com/article/technology/computers/operating-systems/windows/windows-10/how-to-enable-network-discovery-and-configure-sharing-options-in-windows-10-140265/) must be turned on to find shared resources. [Windows Loop](https://windowsloop.com/turn-on-network-discovery-windows-10/) states, "Windows disables the network discovery feature by default for security reasons."

However, just make a desktop shortcut to the other PC's resource using [UNC path](https://www.lifewire.com/unc-universal-naming-convention-818230) as you've done using *Run*, e.g. `\\JOXPS13\PUBLIC`, and click the link to open the folder on the remote machine, *without* having to enable Network Discovery. This is faster and more stable than searching in Explorer *Network*.

Comment: Thanks for the timely comment.  I double-checked, and I have Network Discovery turned ON on both PC's, so you would think that would do the job ;)